# Is there a get() for instance variables?

Tags: python

For Python dicts, one can do

```
a = {'b': 5}
c = a.get('c', 0)
```

in order to have a default value in case the key doesn't exist. Is there a similar "default value" functionality for Python instance variables?

Comment: Looks like a bad design, why do you want this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getattr` builtin function takes an optional third argument, which is returned if an object doesn't have the attribute. Example usage: `getattr(myobj, 'attr', default_value)`